# word for a derangment extended to all subsets

Tags: permutations, terminology

A derangement is a permutation of a set where no element maps to itself, but is there a word for the stricter case where no proper subset of a set maps to itself under a permutation?

For example:

1 2 3 4 5
3 1 2 5 4

is a derangement, but since the image of the subset {1,2,3} under this permutation is still {1,2,3}, this is not a super-derangement.

1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1

has no proper subsets that are unaffected by the operation, so it is a super-derangement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on who you ask, but this is a *cyclic permutation*. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation):

> [A] cyclic permutation (or cycle) is a permutation of the elements of some set X which maps the elements of some subset S of X to each other in a cyclic fashion, while fixing (that is, mapping to themselves) all other elements of X.

This definition leads room for permutations like

```
1 2 3 4 5
3 1 2 4 5
```

being called a cyclic permutation. But:

> Some authors restrict the definition to only those permutations which consist of one nontrivial cycle (that is, no fixed points allowed).

If your set X is fixed, having $n$ elements, these kind of permutations are generally referred to as *n-cycles*.

Comment: Of course, I should have noticed that the only way that could work for all subsets was with a single cycle.